# Image not rendering in Netlify deploy

Tags: image, github, png, netlify

I've built a small demo site in Svelte using Tailwind CSS fetching data from the TVMaze API. Project has been deployed on Netlify, but for some reason the logo image becomes a broken link.

This is the VS code:

[Code from VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYhdS.png)

This is now it renders in localhost:

[Logo render in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0ivx.png)

This is how the file look on GitHub:

[Logo file on GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmN9W.png)

This is how it looks once deployed on Netlify:

[Broken logo on live site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJFNl.png)

I've tried to manipulate the path in various ways, and also different formats of the image (.jpg, .svg) but with no success. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Thanks for now!

Answer (score 0):

You should put the images in your /public folder